# Set Title of UIButton from Selected Row of UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uibutton, uipickerview

Detailed scenario is like this :

I am creating 10 buttons using a loop and setting the tags from 0-9. On tap of each button I am calling a UIPickerView in which I am loading data from different arrays. Till here I am getting the expected results. But I want the selected row from the pickerView should set as the title of respective button.

Way I tried - I stored the selected row in a NSString in the pickerViewDelegate method and trying to setTitle like :

```
[myButton setTitle:selectedString forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

but it's not reflecting in any of the buttons.

Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using interface builder?

Comment: How do you set myButton and selectedString?

Comment: Once check whether the value of picker is saved in selectString. And also check that u get the button tag of particular button clicked.So that u can set title for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your UIButton tap action,**

```
- (IBAction) buttonTaped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{
    myButton=(UIButton *) sender.view; //It will make reference to tapped button,
    //Once you've this, in your picker delegate, you can set title for it
    //myButton should be declare in your controller's header file.
}
```

**or**

```
- (IBAction) buttonTaped:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    myButton=(UIButton *) sender;
}
```

**Your UIPickerView delegate**

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    [myButton setTitle:[yourArray objectAtIndex:row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

**Hope this will helps you!**