# Set Title of UIButton from Selected Row of UIPickerView in swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, uipickerview

I am trying to set my Button title from a selected row from uipickerview. However, I can't seem to find a valid solution.

I have set the variables to be global thus I can access the Selected Variable. However I cant seem to be able to pinpoint exactly when the user clicks the exit button and able to update my button title.

Things I have tried:

- Global Functions ( couldn't work because you cant specify the button you want to change the name of )
- Dispatchqueue.main.async - Did not update my title. The idea here is for it to constantly check for a string change.

The solution I found here is in Obj-C. I tried converting it to swift https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code/ with no luck.
[Set Title of UIButton from Selected Row of UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049096/set-title-of-uibutton-from-selected-row-of-uipickerview)

```
@IBAction func CountryPickButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        Global.setPickerDataSource(data:["Test","test2","test3"])
        Global.setPickerCompletionHandler(int:0)
        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PickerViewPopUpId") as! PickerViewController
        //CountryPickButtonDetector = sender as? UIButton
        self.addChild(popOverVC)
        popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
        popOverVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        popOverVC.callback { value in
        //CountryPickButton.title.text = value
        sender.setTitle(value, for: UIControl.State)
    }
    }
```

---

```
import UIKit
var test = ""

class PickerViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var PickerView: UIPickerView!
    var callback : ((String) -> Void)?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        PickerView.dataSource = self
        PickerView.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBAction func ExitButton(_ sender: Any) {
        switch Global.pickerCompletionHandler {

        case 0:
            callback?(Global.pickerResult ?? "")
            Global.setProfileCountry(string:
                Global.pickerResult ?? "")
        default:
            print("nothing")

        }
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}

extension PickerViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1 // can be more than 1 component like time/date/year
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return Global.pickerDataSource?.count ?? 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        //Global.pickerResult = Global.pickerDataSource?[row]
        Global.setPickerResult(result: Global.pickerDataSource?[row] ?? "Test" )
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return Global.pickerDataSource?[row]
    }


}
```

---

Globals

```
import Foundation

struct Global {
    static var pickerDataSource:[String]? = nil
    static var pickerResult:String? = nil
    static var pickerCompletionHandler:Int? = 0
    static var profileCountry:String? = nil

    static func setPickerDataSource(data:[String]) {
        Global.pickerDataSource = data
    }
    static func setPickerResult(result:String) {
        Global.pickerResult = result
    }
    static func setPickerCompletionHandler(int: Int) {
        Global.pickerCompletionHandler = int
    }
    static func setProfileCountry(string: String)
    {
        Global.profileCountry = string
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't *check* for something. Get notified! Implement the picker view delegate method `didSelectRow` and notify (with callback closure, protocol / delegate or `Notification`) about the change.

Comment: my didselectrow looks like this

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        //Global.pickerResult = Global.pickerDataSource?[row]
        Global.setPickerResult(result: Global.pickerDataSource?[row] ?? "Test" )
    }

how should i change this for it to notify me? @vadian

Comment: In the IBAction you have the reference to the button. Add a callback closure which is called in `didSelectRow`. In the body of the closure set the title

Comment: @vadian I wont lie, Im quite new at this. How do I connect the callback closure and the didselectrow, I have never done a callback closure. Is this coded at the picker view controller or the view controller with the button.

Comment: Unfortunately the code in the question is too vague to provide a concrete suggestion.

Comment: @vadian I added my pickerview for you to take a look at. I believe it is just a standard one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what all that `Global` stuff is, the easiest solution might be to extend `pickerCompletionHandler`, but here is another (easy) one:

- In `PickerViewController` add a callback passing a `String` value and no return value

  ```
  var callback : ((String) -> Void)?
  ```

  and call it in `exitButton` (please, please variable and function names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter)

  ```
  @IBAction func exitButton(_ sender: Any) {
      switch Global.pickerCompletionHandler {

      case 0:
          callback?(Global.pickerResult ?? "")
          Global.setProfileCountry(string:
              Global.pickerResult ?? "")
      default:
          print("nothing")

      }
      self.view.removeFromSuperview()
  }
  ```
- In `countryPickButton` (again: **lowercase** letter) set the callback and set `sender` to the real type. The callback sets the title

  ```
  @IBAction func countryPickButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

      Global.setPickerDataSource(data:["Test","test2","test3"])
      Global.setPickerCompletionHandler(int:0)
      let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PickerViewPopUpId") as! PickerViewController
      popOverVC.callback = { value in 
          sender.setTitle(value, for: .normal)
      }
  ...
  ```

Comment: This gets me "Cannot call value of non-function type ((String) -> Void)?".
I did add var callback : ((String) -> Void)? to pickerViewController,

Ill add my Globals for clarity, it is mainly just so I can communicate information through multiple swift files

Comment: I think it is saying callback is not a function therefore cannot return a value... So am doing something wrong? I have edited the code to put what you added in

Comment: Please read my code carefully. Change the `sender` type of the IBAction to `UIButton` and use `sender.title`. That's exactly the mess when functions are named with starting uppercase letters. And practically the `Global` struct is pointless  if it's only used in the `PickerViewController`.

Comment: I changed sender to UIButton, The same error exists, First, "Cannot assign to property: 'title' is a method" then I changed it to : "
popOverVC.callback { value in
            sender.setTitle(value, for: UIControl.State)
        }
"
"Cannot call value of non-function type '((String) -> Void)?'"

I updated the code again

Comment: This is actually a reuse-able pickerviewcontroller where the data to chose can be changed depending on which screen is using it. Thus I had to set it a global variable. I will be incorporating Login and register token as well in the future

Comment: My apologies, I forgot the `=` after `popOverVC.callback`. Answer updated.