# Update UIButton title with array data using UIPickerView selected row

Tags: ios, swift

This question has been covered before but I'm just not getting it.

- ([Set Title of UIButton from Selected Row of UIPickerView in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54921382/set-title-of-uibutton-from-selected-row-of-uipickerview-in-swift))
- ([Set Title of UIButton from Selected Row of UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049096/set-title-of-uibutton-from-selected-row-of-uipickerview))

I have three buttons to show a UIPickerView.

```
button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showPicker), for: .touchUpInside)
button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showPicker), for: .touchUpInside)
button3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showPicker), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Depending on the button clicked, the picker data (modelData) and tag are updated.

```
@objc func showFilterPicker(sender: UIButton)
    if sender.tag == 238 {
        modelData = someStringArray1
        filterPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        filterPickerView.tag = 2238
    } else if sender.tag == 239 {
        modelData = someStringArray2
        filterPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        filterPickerView.tag = 2239
    } else if sender.tag == 240 {
        modelData = someStringArray3
        filterPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        filterPickerView.tag = 2240
    }
}
```

To update the button title

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if filterPickerView.tag == 2238 {
        button1.setTitle(modelData[row], for: .normal)
    } else if filterPickerView.tag == 2239 {
        button2.setTitle(modelData[row], for: .normal)
    } else if filterPickerView.tag == 2240 {
        button3.setTitle(modelData[row], for: .normal)
    }
}
```

However, this does not work.

Any suggestions or a more detailed example of the linked answers would be helpful, thanks.

--

view hierarchy

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    view.addSubview(outerView)
    outerView.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.addSubview(button1)
    containerView.addSubview(button2)
    containerView.addSubview(button3)
    view.addSubview(pickerContainerView)
    pickerContainerView.addSubview(filterPickerView)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean *"this does not work"*? `didSelectRow` isn't called? It's called, but you get the wrong string? It's called, you get the right string, but the button doesn't update visually?

Comment: `didSelectRow` gets called but after that method completes the views containing the picker and button disappear

Comment: Nothing you have posted indicates anything about where your buttons or picker view are in the view hierarchy, and nothing in your code would cause what you're describing. Since you're new to Stack Overflow, welcome, but please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: The picker and button are in separate subviews of the main view. does this make a difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Title of UIButton from Selected Row of UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049096/set-title-of-uibutton-from-selected-row-of-uipickerview)

Comment: Yes i already pointed out this is a duplicate because i don't understand that solution

Comment: @DonMag i updated to show the view hierarchy. hopefully it makes more sense now

Comment: @dean - start with the basics... add a picker view to a view, give it data, and use a `print()` statement in `didSelectRow` to confirm it works. Then add 3 buttons to change the data, confirm `didSelectRow` still works. Then have `didSelectRow` update the title of the buttons, confirm it sill works. Then add the elements to a scroll view... confirm it works.

Comment: @DonMag I have followed your instructions and i can confirm that when the buttons and picker are added to the same view the picker updates the titles as expected

Comment: @dean - ok... then continue step-by-step. Embed the buttons in a view, embed the picker view in a view. Confirm it works. Add those views to a scroll view. Confirm it works. If at some point it *stops* working, look at what you just changed to figure out why.

Comment: @DonMag Everything works as expected until the buttons and picker are added to separate views, then they disappear when the `didSelectRow` is called (back to the original situation).. i know now this error makes sense, i can't directly change the button title from the picker as they are in separate hierarchies. But I do not know how to fix the issue

Comment: @dean - Unless you're actually using different view controllers as child view controllers, it doesn't matter whether the elements are in the same view hierarchy or not. I'll post a complete functional example as an answer, and you can see what's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete, functional example. No IBOutlets or IBActions, so just assign a new view controller to this class:

```
//
//  DeanViewController.swift
//  TestProj
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 8/20/19.
//

import UIKit

class DeanViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    let button1: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        b.setTitle("Button 1", for: .normal)
        return b
    }()

    let button2: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        b.setTitle("Button 2", for: .normal)
        return b
    }()

    let button3: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        b.setTitle("Button 3", for: .normal)
        return b
    }()


    let filterPickerView: UIPickerView = {
        let v = UIPickerView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let buttonStackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.spacing = 8
        return v
    }()

    let containerView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return v
    }()

    let pickerContainerView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        return v
    }()

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        return v
    }()

    let data1 = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    let data2 = ["This", "is", "a", "Test"]
    let data3 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

    var modelData: [String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add the 3 buttons to the stack view
        buttonStackView.addArrangedSubview(button1)
        buttonStackView.addArrangedSubview(button2)
        buttonStackView.addArrangedSubview(button3)

        // add the stack view to the container view
        containerView.addSubview(buttonStackView)

        // add the container view to the scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)

        // add the picker view to its container view
        pickerContainerView.addSubview(filterPickerView)

        // add the picker container view to the scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(pickerContainerView)

        // add the scroll view to the view
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        // setup the constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            buttonStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            buttonStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            buttonStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            buttonStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            filterPickerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pickerContainerView.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            filterPickerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pickerContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            filterPickerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pickerContainerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            filterPickerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pickerContainerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            pickerContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            pickerContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            pickerContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            pickerContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            pickerContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -40.0),

            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),

            ])

        modelData = data1
        filterPickerView.tag = 1

        filterPickerView.dataSource = self
        filterPickerView.delegate = self

        button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func btnTap(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {

        if sender == button1 {
            modelData = data1
            filterPickerView.tag = 1
        } else if sender == button2 {
            modelData = data2
            filterPickerView.tag = 2
        } else {
            modelData = data3
            filterPickerView.tag = 3
        }

        filterPickerView.reloadAllComponents()

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        var btn: UIButton?
        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            btn = button1
        } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
            btn = button2
        } else {
            btn = button3
        }
        btn?.setTitle(modelData[row], for: .normal)
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return modelData[row]
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return modelData.count
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Blue is the background color of the scroll view; 
Green is the background color of the picker container view
Cyan is the background color of the buttons container view (the buttons are also embedded in a stack view)

Tapping each button changes the data in the picker, and selecting a row in the picker changes the title of the associated button.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have compared the code and it is now working for my case. although i couldn't find the difference exactly this is a very clear solution for me to follow